# div in verilog for numbers 0-9

Tags: verilog, fpga

im coding and synthesizing a module "divider" in an fpga. Inputs A,B are considered to produce output div, which is equal to A div B. Ive tested my code with a testbench module, and it was working properly. However, when im synthesizing it into my fpga, certain part of the code is not working as intended.
Presenting the code, then I will explain what fails.

```
module divider(A,B,clk,reset,div,temp);
input [3:0]A,B;
input clk,reset;
output [3:0]div;
output [3:0]temp;
reg [3:0]temp,div_result;
reg [2:0] counter;
always@(A,B) 
begin
    //temp=4'd0;
    counter=3'd1;
end

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
if (reset) counter=1;
else
begin
    if (B==4'd1) div_result=A;
    else if (B==4'd0) div_result=4'b1111;
    else if (A<B) div_result=0;
    else if (A==B) div_result=1;
    else if (A>B)
        begin
            temp=A-counter*B;
            if (temp>=B)  counter=counter+3'd1;
            else begin
            div_result=counter;

            end


        end




end
assign div=div_result;
endmodule

module test();
reg [3:0] A,B;
reg clk,reset;
wire [3:0]div;
wire [2:0] temp;
divider kappa(A,B,clk,reset,div,temp);
initial
begin
#0 A=4'd8; B=4'd2; clk=0; reset=1;
#1 reset=0;
#50 B=4'd1;
#50 B=4'd3;
#50 B=4'd4;
#50 B=4'd5;
#50 B=4'd8;
#50 B=4'd9;
end
always #5 clk=~clk;
endmodule
```

The result appears as it should in almost all cases, except when the div needs to be counted, and is greater than 1. ie, 7 div 7 works properly, 8 div 5 works properly, 6 div 0 works properly BUT 8 div 4 is NOT. neither 9 div 2 etc. They all produce the output 0.

I have created many modules, working fine. For some reason, even though I use clk to count how many times B can "fit" into A (Since A>B, B "fits" at least once, in A,so the counter is set to 1. If A-1*B>=B, it fits again. So counter=2 etc). This logic is produced by the clk pulse.

Can you help me figure out the problem?

Comment: I noticed something that might not help but it should be corrected. You are passing 3 bit width `wire [2:0] temp;` in `test` module to 4 bit width `output [3:0]temp;` in `divider` module.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of blocking statements in the clocking block is causing this issue.

```
temp=A-counter*B;
if (temp>=B)  counter=counter+3'd1;
```

Above you try to assign temp and use its right after this will work fine in simulation but in hardware it will not. First and foremost convert all your blocking to non blocking statements and re simulate the design to see if it still works as expected. Then try changing the temp logic above by making temp combinational

```
wire[3:0] temp;
assign temp = A - (counter * B);
```

Also other then reset I don't see the counter resetting.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will try your suggestion. The counter is resetting in the upper always block, whenever inputs A or B are changing.

Comment: You can not control counter from two always blocks, It wont synthesise correctly. but your simulator will allow it.

Comment: @Morgan Yup. the code is not synthesising correctly. I need to alter the logic of the code.